# can't push chat notification

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification

how to show notification in my app? because if I send a message can't show notification in others.
manifest here

```
    <service
        android:name=".FirebaseService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_SERVICE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".FirebaseMessaging"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

class apiservice

```
public interface APIService {

@Headers({
        "Content-Type:application/json",
        "Authorization:key=WKFqL"
})

@POST("fcm/send")
Call<Respon> sendnotif(@Body Pengirim body); }
```

class respon

```
public class Respon {

    public int sukses;
}
```

class firebase messaging

```
public class FirebaseMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    SharedPreferences shr = getSharedPreferences("SP_USER", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String savedc = shr.getString("Current_USERID", "None");

    String sent = remoteMessage.getData().get("sent");
    String user = remoteMessage.getData().get("user");
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if(firebaseUser != null && sent != null && sent.equals(firebaseUser.getUid())){
        if(!savedc.equals(user) ){
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
                sendnotif(remoteMessage);
            }
            else
            {
                sendnormal(remoteMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void sendnormal(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    String user = remoteMessage.getData().get("user");
    String icon = remoteMessage.getData().get("icon");
    String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
    String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");

    RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
    int a = Integer.parseInt(user.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatAct.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("hisUid", user);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, a, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri soundur = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(Integer.parseInt(icon))
            .setContentText(body)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(soundur)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    int j = 0;
    if (a>0){
        j=a;

    }
    notificationManager.notify(j, builder.build());

}


private void sendnotif(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    String user = remoteMessage.getData().get("user");
    String icon = remoteMessage.getData().get("icon");
    String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
    String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");

    RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
    int a = Integer.parseInt(user.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatAct.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("hisUid", user);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, a, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri soundur = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    Notif notif = new Notif(this);
    Notification.Builder builder = notif.getnotif(title, body, pendingIntent, soundur, icon);


     int j = 0;
    if (a>0){
        j=a;

    }
    notif.getNotificationManager().notify(j, builder.build());
} }
```

clas firebase service

```
public class FirebaseService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    super.onTokenRefresh();
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String tokenrf = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    if(user != null){
        updatetoken(tokenrf);
    }
}

private void updatetoken(String tokenrf) {
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Tokens");
    Tokenclass token = new Tokenclass(tokenrf);
    ref.child(user.getUid()).setValue(token);


} }
```

class chat for sendnotif

```
 FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference databaseReferenceuser;

ValueEventListener seenlist;
DatabaseReference databaseReferenceseen;

List<Datachat> chatlist;
Adapterchat adapterchat;

APIService apiService;
boolean notify = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbr);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.cht_recycler);
    imgprof = findViewById(R.id.profimg);
    namacht = findViewById(R.id.namacht);
    statuson = findViewById(R.id.statuson);
    pesanet = findViewById(R.id.pesanet);
    sendbtn = findViewById(R.id.sendbtn);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    Intent chatt = getIntent();
    hisUid = chatt.getStringExtra("hisUid");

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
     apiService = getRetrofit("https://fcm.googleapis.com/").create(APIService.class);


    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReferenceuser = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Users");


sendbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            notify = true;

            String pesan = pesanet.getText().toString().trim();
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(pesan)){

                Toast.makeText(ChatAct.this, "Tidak dapat mengirim pesan kosong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else{
                kirimpesan(pesan);
            }
            pesanet.setText("");
        }
    });

private void kirimpesan(final String pesan) {
    DatabaseReference databaseReference =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    String timestamp = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());

    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("sender", myUid);
    hashMap.put("receiver", hisUid);
    hashMap.put("message", pesan);
    hashMap.put("seen", false);
    hashMap.put("timestamp", timestamp);
    databaseReference.child("Chats").push().setValue(hashMap);



    String msg = pesan;
    DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(myUid);
    database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            DataUser user = dataSnapshot.getValue(DataUser.class);
            if(notify){
                sendnotif(hisUid, user.getName(), pesan);
            }
            notify = false;

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void sendnotif(final String hisUid, final String name, final String pesan) {

    DatabaseReference alltoken = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Tokens");
    Query query = alltoken.orderByKey().equalTo(hisUid);
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Tokenclass tokenclass = ds.getValue(Tokenclass.class);
                Datanotif data = new Datanotif(myUid, name+":"+pesan, "Pesan Baru", hisUid, R.drawable.ic_usr_name);
                Pengirim pengirim = new Pengirim(data, tokenclass.getToken());
                 apiService.sendnotif(pengirim)
                         .enqueue(new Callback<Respon>() {
                             @Override
                             public void onResponse(Call<Respon> call, retrofit2.Response<Respon> response) {
                                 Toast.makeText(ChatAct.this, ""+response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                             }

                             @Override
                             public void onFailure(Call<Respon> call, Throwable t) {

                             }
                         });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

how to show notification in my app? because if I send a message can't show notification in others.

Answer (score 0):

It's a paid service you should pay to firebase

as upgrade via spark

Comment: Really? Its not free?